# Combining Rotation and Graduated Colors in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, point, feature-layer

Is there a way to rotate the symbols of a point feature layer (with a given rotation out of the attribute table) that is displayed as graduated color layer?

I can see the option in the graduated color menu, but it is greyed out.

[image: point]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in ArcMap, but it can be done.

1. Set up your graduated colour as you have and click on advanced and
   you will see it greyed out.
2. Click on Categories and select Unique Values
3. Now go back to graduated colour and click on advanced button, hey presto it is now available!

Comment: It really worked! :D Thanks a lot, this was a big help!

Comment: @Fischkopf Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.